GSAP ScrollTrigger || The Animation Happen When I Scroll back but not working (can't see the Carousel at all) when I scroll down
I am trying to create a rounded carousel with scroll using GSAP ScrollTrigger , I add a section that have 300vh height and in it a parallax section that contain a morphing from wave SVG to a Half of Circle SVG and when morph done the carousel will start but when I scroll down I can't see any carousel , and scroll back can see it how can I fix this?
here is my code :
import React from 'react'
import ParallaxSection from './ParallaxSection'
import Carousel from './Carousel'
import gsap from 'gsap';
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger';
import rocket from '../assets/Rocket.svg';
import asra from '../assets/Asra3_001.svg';
import wifi from '../assets/svg/Wifi.svg';
import awsa from '../assets/Awsa3_001.svg';
import savings from '../assets/svg/fading/Savings.svg';
import awfar from '../assets/Awfar_001.svg';
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const svgElements = [
    <img src={rocket} alt="rocket" width={'50%'} />,
    <img src={asra} alt="asra" width={'100%'} />,
    <img src={wifi} alt="wifi" width={'50%'} />,
    <img src={awsa} alt="awsa" width={'100%'} />,
    <img src={savings} alt="savings" width={'50%'} />,
    <img src={awfar} alt="awfar"  width={'100%'}/>,
  ];
function SecondSection() {
  return (
    <div className="w-full second-section relative h-[300vh]">
        <ParallaxSection/>
        <div className="absolute z-50 left-1/3 top-28">
        <Carousel svgs={svgElements}/>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SecondSection

import React, { useEffect } from 'react';


import MorphingSVG from './morph/MorphingSVG';



function ParallaxSection() {

  return (
    <div
    className="parallax-section sticky top-20 bg-green h-[100vh] w-[100vw] overflow-x-hidden">
        <MorphingSVG/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ParallaxSection

import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";


const Carousel = ({ svgs }) => {
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

  const itemsRef = useRef([]);
  const carouselRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const radius = 850; // radius of the circle
    const totalItems = itemsRef.current.length;

    // Set initial position of items
    itemsRef.current.forEach((item, index) => {
      const angle = (index / totalItems) * 360;
      const x = radius * Math.cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
      const y = radius * Math.sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180));

      gsap.set(item, {
        x,
        y,
        transformOrigin: "center center", // Ensuring each item rotates around its own center
      });
    });

    // Rotate the carousel with scroll
    gsap.to(carouselRef.current, {
      rotation: 360, // Complete rotation around the center
      transformOrigin: "center center", // Rotate around the center of the carousel
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: document.querySelector(".second-section"), // Ensure this element exists
        start: "top 100%",
        end: "+=100% bottom",
        scrub: true,
        markers: true, // Debugging markers
        pin: carouselRef.current, // Pin the carousel to the center
      },
      ease: "none",
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className="carousel"
      ref={carouselRef}
      style={{
        position: "relative",
        width: "600px",
        height: "600px",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      {svgs.map((svg, i) => (
        <div
          key={i}
          className="item"
          ref={(el) => (itemsRef.current[i] = el)}
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            transformOrigin: "center center", // Ensuring the correct origin for each item
          }}
        >
          {svg}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Carousel;

import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { gsap } from 'gsap';
import { MorphSVGPlugin } from 'gsap/MorphSVGPlugin';
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger';

gsap.registerPlugin(MorphSVGPlugin, ScrollTrigger);

const MorphingSVG = () => {
  const svgRef = useRef(null);
  const pathRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const svgElement = svgRef.current;
    const pathElement = pathRef.current;

    gsap.fromTo(pathElement, 
      { morphSVG: '#gear',
        scaleY: 1,
       }, 
      {
        morphSVG: '#x',
        scaleY:1.5,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: svgElement,
          start: 'top 60%',
          end: 'bottom bottom',
          scrub: true,
        },
      }
    )
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='flex w-full h-full absolute bottom-0 justify-end' style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
<svg  ref={svgRef} width="100%" viewBox="0 0 300 100" fill='#ffcd00'>
  <path
    ref={pathRef}
    d="M0,30 Q30,10 60,30 T120,30 T180,30 T240,30 T300,30 V100 H0 Z"
    fill="#ffcd00"
    stroke="black"
    strokeWidth="0"
  />
  {/* Hidden paths for morphing */}
  <defs>
    <path id="gear" d="M0,30 Q30,10 60,30 T120,30 T180,30 T240,30 T300,30 V100 H0 Z" />
    <path id="x" d="M 0 100 A 150 100 0 0 1 300 100 L 0 100 Z" />
  </defs>
</svg>

    </div>
  );
};

export default MorphingSVG;

